# What is this で (in bold)　and this こと (in bold)?

Tags: grammar

あなたが常識だと思っていたこと**で**、ほかの人におかしいと言われ、不思議だと思ったことがありますか。どんな**こと**ですか。

First, here's how I understand this sentence:
Have you ever thought that this is common sense, or been said by other people that this is strange, or thought that this is strange (or marvelous?)
What **situations** are/were these?

1. I guess this で is a connective form of です?
2. I think こと is in a pronominal function here and represents what was described before.

I can't remember having encounter these two points before. I also feel unsure about my translation, because I've never used "or" instead of "and" or similar for this kind of connection. But with "and", while it wouldn't be completely wrong, it feels slightly off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try breaking it up into three separate sentences:

あなたが常識だと思っていた    You thought it was common sense

ほかの人におかしいと言われた     You were told by somebody else that it was weird

不思議だと思った   You thought that was strange

Now link them together:

あなたが常識だと思っていたことで、ほかの人におかしいと言われ、不思議だと思った
 It was something that you thought was common sense and [yet] you were told by somebody else that it was weird, and you thought it was strange [that they would say that]

The  ことがありますか  at the end ought to have its usual meaning of "has it ever happened to you that", "have you ever had the experience of", "have you ever". If it does, then this would mean "Has it ever happened to you that you have thought that something was common sense, but somebody else has said to you that it was weird and you have thought it was strange that they should say that?"

But given the presence of  こと at the beginning of the sentence and in the next sentence I suppose it's possible that it has its full meaning here. So it might be "Is there anything that you thought was common sense but somebody else said was weird and you thought it was strange they should say that? What sort of thing was it?"

That's my best shot. It seems to me to be a sentence that's not easy to parse.

Answer (score 1):

あなたが常識だと思っていたこと what you have thought is a common sense

で、 regarding (what you have thought is a common sense)

ほかの人におかしいと言われ、someone else pointed out that it(the common sense)'s strange/incorrect/wrong and so

不思議だと思ったこと you are mystified/perplexed (by being told it's おかしい)

がありますか。 have you ever experienced that (~を不思議におもった)

> I guess this で is a connective form of です?

I don't know what you mean by "connective form" but I guess perhaps right.

> I think こと is in a pronominal function here and represents what was described before.

correct.